# Информация об импортирующем модуле

Tags: python

Добрый день!
В скрипте импортирую модуль, в котором мне нужно знать имя этого скрипта. `__name__`, `__file__` всегда дают имя самого модуля. Постоянно передавать в функции имя скрипта не хотелось бы. Подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать.
Спасибо.

Comment: Воспользуйтесь модулем inspect.

Comment: Большое спасибо, помогло.

Comment: Расскажите что именно использовали. А то я так сходу ответ не нашел

Comment: Я использовал функцию stack(), которая возвращает список записей, соответствующих текущему кадру стека. При использовании функции из импортированного модуля в скрипте, в стеке можно найти название скрипта. Может это не оптимально и можно сделать как то по другому, но и так работает)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Имя выполняемого скрипта находится в [`sys.argv[0]`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sys.html#sys.argv).